# How to make background services in Kotlin every amount of time

Tags: kotlin, notifications, background-process

I'm learning Kotlin and I'm making my first app to track stock market changes.

I'm planing to make the app check for prices in the background (every hour maybe) and send a notification to the user if there is any change in prices.

I have searched the Internet and haven't found any helpful solution.

Comment: This is something you can easily find many tutorials for on the internet. I guess you need to search better.

Comment: AlarmManager...